# how to merge a row data into above row..?which have few column same

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

[image: I have a table like this:-]

I have a table like.

And i want to answer like a table below:-

[image: and now i want to answer like this:-]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use aggregation, like this:

```
select empcode, coode, finyear, wef,
       max(cl_opn_bal) as cl_open_bal,
       . . .
from table t
group by empcode, coode, finyear, wef;
```

Comment: you are lightning fast, i just prepared the solution and just was pushing the answer Button saw

 
answered 3 mins ago

Gordon Linoff
326k1882136

Comment: just in case anybody intrested....

Select * into #testtable FROM 
(
select 1 col1  ,  'b' col2 , null col3 , 2 col4 , null col5  union all
select 1 col1  ,  'b' col2 , 1 , null  , null union all
select 1 col1  ,  'b' col2 , null  , null  , 3 

) Tbl


select col1 , col2 , max (col3) col3 , max(col4) col4 , max(col5) col5 from #testtable
Group by col1 , col2

Comment: great!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!